# Find the address of missing entry

Tags: algorithm

A person makes numerical entries into a two dimensional grid. They miss making one entry. What is the most efficient algorithm to find the row and column of the missing entry?

Apart from a simple sequential search row-by-row or column-by-column I see no other way. But, apparently, there is a fast algorithm. My idea is that there is no way around having to check every entry so at least rows*columns steps are needed.

Comment: You could add all locations in a Hashmap before the person makes entries. Later, whenever he adds an entry, remove that cell from the map. After he/she completes, if the hashmap size is more than 0, you know the ones which aren't filled.

Comment: Technically, you will have to pre-process  the cells. So, it would be row-by-row, so that's inevitable, however after the person completes filling, it is O(1) which is you never need to recheck the 2D grid again.

Comment: The matrix/grid is given to one after being filled. So pre-processing cannot be done.

Comment: ok, in that case, row-by-row is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmically speaking, without any additional constraints, the sequential search is optimal by the following argument. Checking every possible entry yields a linear runtime complexity. Any algorithm with a strictly lower runtime complexity would be unable to inspect every possible entry, which would mean that there are entries which do not contribute to the result, which is not the case. Hence, a linear runtime bound is optimal.

Comment: Thank you. So you mean rows*columns steps are inevitable, right?

Comment: @user2371765 The downvote was not by me. Yes, inspection of every entry is inevitable (without any additional mechanics).